# SVN update ignoring all incoming changes

Tags: svn

I want to commit code to SVN, but I get errors, because I need to update my project before commiting. Can I execute `update` command ignoring all incoming changes?

Error is:

```
svn: E160024: Commit failed (details follow):
 resource out of date; try updating
```

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I edited question. Please review it.

Comment: what is the output if you run `svn update` ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor please, read question again. I don't want to run `update` command.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to ignore the changes that would be coming down from the `svn update`? Are you fearful of losing your changes? The `svn update` will attempt to merge any changes from the server into the files you changed locally. It is highly unlikely that your changes would be reverted due to the update.

What you can do before performing your commit is to do an `svn log` from the root of your checkout and examining the changes committed by others to the server while you were working on your local checkout. Then, when you perform the `svn update` on your side, you will know what to expect.

If you *really* want to perform the update without changing anything, you could do it using this:

```
> cd path/to/root/of/checkout/
> svn up --depth EMPTY
```

... but I haven't ever needed to do that and I urge you to run it without the `--depth` switch

Answer (score 0):

`svupdate` does not delete your local changes. It would try to update your changed files with latest changes by merging them correctly. If there are some conflicts, it says so. Then you resolve these conflicts yourself.